# NHibernate, proxies and equality

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.1 and found very interesting problem.
In my domain model I defined two classes: Carriage and CarriageRequest, referencing each other. Because lazy loading is turned on, when I access carriage.CarriageRequest - it points to a proxy object. That is okay. But when I invoke any method, defined in CarriageRequest class, 'this' references to a third object instance.

Example:

```
class CarriageRequest
{
  public virtual void Test(CarriageRequest instance)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(this, instance)); // prints FALSE
  }
}

class Carriage
{ 
  public virtual CarriageRequest CarriageRequest { get; set; }
}

...
var carriage = session.Get<Carriage>(123);
carriage.CarriageRequest.Test(carriage.CarriageRequest);
```

So it looks like NHibernate proxies wrap original objects and forward all method invocations to wrapped objects. How can I use "==" in this case?
I need to do something like this:

```
var shipment = (from sh in Carriage.Shipments where sh.CarriageRequest == this & sh.Warehouse == waybill.Warehouse select sh).FirstOrDefault();
```

This code is executed **inside** proxied object, so 'shipment' is always null, because 'sh.CarriageRequest == this' is always false. Because sh.CarriageRequest is a proxy, and this is a wrapped original instance.

Comment: My query can be modified to use this.Equals(sh.CarriageRequest) instead of operator ==, but this looks like only a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried overloading the '==' operator so that it uses Equals ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: No. I thought that NHibernate is smart enough to understand, that by wrapping original object with a proxy, it breaks usages like mine and so it should introduce a way to resolve this issue automatically.

Comment: Not sure NH is involved as this seems to be pure linq (no translation to SQL here) interesting, this kind of operator overloading seems to appear in NH Tests sources https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/612d1b6874a0067f1a9ff1f052ad90f12ce21f1c/src/NHibernate.Test/NHSpecificTest/NH1612/Person.cs#L19 and  https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/612d1b6874a0067f1a9ff1f052ad90f12ce21f1c/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Address.cs#L64

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's pure LINQ, but this query is comparing 'this' instance, retrieved by NHibernate with elements from Shipments collection, retrieved by NHibernate too :-) And while NHibernate guarantees reference equality inside one session, my case looks like violation of this guarantee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, NHibernate guarantees reference equality for loaded objects within the same session. And if using lazy-loading, it wraps real object with a proxy and every method invocation on a proxy is forwarded to the wrapped object. So, inside this object every reference comparison between 'this' and the same object, loaded from session, will fail (because it will be a different, proxy, object).

So, the only way to resolve this issue is to use Equals method or compare by primary keys.

Comment: NB: this behavior takes place onlu with references/belongs_to properties. For collections (HasMany) there are no proxies anywhere.