# Hibernate and Equality checks with lazy loaded objects

Tags: c#, hibernate, lazy-loading, equality

I had some fun with hibernate. A function like that:

```
public class Key
{
    public virtual bool IsEqual(Key key)
    {
        return this == key;
    }
}
```

One would expect this function to always return true if the parameter was the same as the instance where IsEqual was called upon:

```
Assert.IsTrue(MyKey.IsEqual(MyKey));
```

But this is only the case as long as the instance "myKey" is not a lazily loaded object / proxy. A KeyProxy will delegate that call to the internal Key object that is wrapped, and this results in the wrapped object to be compared with the Proxy object (which will in turn fail).

Basically, it has also been discussed here : [NHibernate, proxies and equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901778/nhibernate-proxies-and-equality?s=1|3.6175)

The solution there is a little bit disappointing. Overriding equals to compare the primary key properties has the drawback that it only works for objects that already have a value, whereas new objects don´t have a primary key value until saved. I could try to force new objects to directly receive a valid primary key value, but that doesnt sound like a great way of handling this issue.

Is there a better (more general) way known to handle such situations? Would´nt overriding Equals and comparing with a unique (non-persisted) property just do the trick?

Something like that?

```
public object Identifier {get; private set;}

public Key()
{
    Identifer = new object();
}

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     if (obj == null)
     {
        return false;
     }
     Key k = obj as Key;
     if (k == null)
     {
        return false;
     }
     return this.Identifier == key.Identifier;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this and other problems, such as using an identity column as the primary key, we added a GUID to the base class of our domain model, object creation is handled by factory classes that gives each entity a GUID and this is then persisted as part of the entity.

The GUID is then used to compare entities, basicly we use it in the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods.

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.EqualityIdentifier.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        IDomainObject Obj = obj as IDomainObject 

        if (Obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.EqualityIdentifier == Obj.EqualityIdentifier;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds very similar to my approach, but why is it persisted?

Comment: The only other option would be to create a GUID every time an instance is created, if for whatever reason we ever had two instances of what is essentially one domain entity, a detached instance or two instances in two different data contexts for example, they would not compare as equal if they had different GUIDs to identify them. If you can live with it just use a GUID as a primary key instead of an integer using identity generation.

Answer (score 0):

To have a minimum performance impact, I decided to use a non-persisted readonly int property "Identifier" that is filled (lazily/at first access) by a small static and thread-safe number generator method.

```
  private static int _equalityIdentifierSequence;

  private static int GenerateEqualityIdentifier()
  {
     Interlocked.Increment(ref _equalityIdentifierSequence);         
     return _equalityIdentifierSequence;
  }
```

I am quite comfortable with the fact that two objects that were loaded from different sessions but are representing the same entity are regarded as "not equal", so the GUID strategy did not look that promising to me. The original problem of proxies compared with their wrapped objects seems to be solved with that.